# Isr is called all the time, even with no data sent to UART

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I wanted to enable isr for IDLE detection on my USART1, but after I set appropriate flag in control register, I see in debugger that isr procedure is called all the time. I mean, I've set a breakpoint on that procedure, so I can see that it is called all the time, not just one, or even zero times. To be honest I expected that isr procedure won't be called until I sent some data to UART...

Below is my code.
I use STM32F103 and libopencm3.

```
extern "C" {
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
  #include <libopencm3/cm3/systick.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/timer.h>
  #include <libopencm3/cm3/nvic.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/usart.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/dma.h>
}

static void rcc_setup()
{
  //Peripherals clock
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOB); 
}

int main()
{
  rcc_setup();
  
  rcc_clock_setup_in_hse_8mhz_out_72mhz();

  systick_set_clocksource(STK_CSR_CLKSOURCE_AHB_DIV8);
  systick_set_reload(8999);

  systick_interrupt_enable();
  systick_counter_enable();

  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_DMA1);

  // -> GPIO
  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_TX, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50_MHZ, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_PUSHPULL, GPIO_USART1_TX);

  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_RX, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_OPENDRAIN, GPIO_USART1_RX);

  // -> Configuration
  usart_set_mode(USART1, USART_MODE_TX_RX);
  usart_set_baudrate(USART1, 9600);
  usart_set_parity(USART1, USART_PARITY_NONE);
  usart_set_databits(USART1, 8);
  usart_set_stopbits(USART1, 1);
  usart_set_flow_control(USART1, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

  USART_CR1(USART1) |= USART_CR1_IDLEIE; //without this, the isr is not called

  nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_USART1_IRQ);

  // -> Enable 
  usart_enable(USART1);


  while(true)
  {
    [[maybe_unused]] int x = 10;
  }
}

void usart1_isr()
{
  [[maybe_unused]]auto x = (USART_CR1(USART1) & USART_CR1_IDLEIE);
  [[maybe_unused]]auto y = (USART_SR(USART1) & USART_FLAG_IDLE);

    if (((USART_CR1(USART1) & USART_CR1_IDLEIE) != 0) &&
        ((USART_SR(USART1) & USART_FLAG_IDLE) != 0))
  {
    [[maybe_unused]] auto x = USART1_SR;
    [[maybe_unused]] auto y = USART1_DR; 

    // process_rx();

  }
}
```

Comment: Almost every ISR of any kind requires you to clear the interrupt source flag(s) from within the ISR.

Comment: I'm guessing `maybe_unused` prevents a compiler warning.  But does it prevent the compiler from optimizing away the read from USART1_DR?  If you step through the ISR does USART1_DR really get read?  Does turning off optimizations help?  Does making `x, y` volatile help?

Comment: I removed maybe_unused, I made x,y volatile, I added some code that do some conditional moves depending on DR value. Nothing helped.

Comment: @bielu000 the problem is in yout magic macros and variables. I use  idle interrupt in all my production code and it works fine. By advice is to use STM provided CMSIS headers and macros not third party bad headers and libraries. It **always** works as expected.

Comment: Nope it neither by macros nor by peripheral addresses. At this moment my isr for usart1 is exactly the same like in HAL implementation. I also compared addresses that I'm reading from and they are the same like in HAL.

Answer (score 1):

In case flags are to be cleared by reads, as is sometimes done in certain UART or SPI peripherals, you should do it like this:

```
void usart1_isr (void)
{
   // read registers in well-defined, clear order to ensure flags are cleared
   volatile uint32_t usart_sr = USART1_SR; // MUST be volatile 
   volatile uint32_t usart_dr = USART1_DR;

   ...
   if(usart_sr == USART_FLAG_IDLE) // check the local variable, not the register
   ....   
}
```

In particular, ***you should not use the brain-damaged C++11 auto keyword in embedded systems!***. That one is discarding the volatile qualifier from the local variable, since `(USART_CR1(USART1) & USART_CR1_IDLEIE)` is a lvalue of type `int`. Which in turn can lead to the compiler failing to generate instructions corresponding to the actual register reads.

Simple example demonstrating one of the many dangers of C++11 `auto`:

```
volatile int a=1;
auto b = a & 1; // b is now int, not volatile int

int* pa = &a; // not OK since a is volatile
int* pb = &b; // OK since b is not volatile
```

I would strongly recommend to port this program to C as soon as possible. Or at least to C++03.

---

EDIT

Ok so now I RTFM for this part and apparently you can also clear the SR by writing 0 to it, in most cases. Which flags that causes interrupts depend on how you set up the CR register. You set `USART_CR1(USART1) |= USART_CR1_IDLEIE;` to generate interrupts *when the line is idle* and then you clear the idle bit by reading the SR from inside the ISR.

So you have told the program to generate endless interrupts when the line is idle and that's what it does. Ditch the `IDLEIE` bit, you should only get interrupts for TX or RX, and ideally also cover OR and FE.

Comment: I changed my code and it doesn't change anything. I've also tried to use the LL_USART_ClearFlag_IDLE function in my isr - I copied function body from STM Hal implementation, and still it doesn't work. I've also compared addresses of SR and DR registers with those defined in HAL and they are the same. Assembly code looks fine, there are reads from SR and DR registers. I'm not sending anything over the USART. MCU is just connected to FT232RL. So my mind is blank. I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: @bielu000 Set a breakpoint inside the ISR and check the SR. What flags are set?

Comment: Following flags in SR are set: IDLE, TC, TXE.

Comment: Ok I see, but I can't agree that I shouldn't use IDLE interrupt. I want to use DMA with this USART, but the data is variable length, so using TC and HT interrupts from DMA is not proper in this case. Using rx interrupt in case of using DMA is unhelpfull beacause I want to avoid calling isr after each byte is received. Therefore one of the reseonable way to combine those things is to use IDLE line detection.  You can find some details here -> https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2017/07/stm32-tutorial-efficiently-receive-uart-data-using-dma/ Btw. thanks for that 'auto' explanation.

Comment: @bielu000 DMA is another story entirely. If you don't call the ISR for each byte, then how are you going to save those bytes? What your program does currently is: check for IDLE: ok line is IDLE, generate interrupt, clear IDLE status, line is still IDLE, generate new interrupt... over and over. I think you need to synchornize the IDLE interrupts with the DMA buffer reads, in order to make any sense of it.

Comment: It could be my misunderstanding of IDLE line usage. 
I thought that may looks in this way: I send e.g. 10 bytes over the USART -> DMA is handling those bytes and copies them into the buffer - after those bytes are sent, the IDLE line is detected, so I can , clear the IDLE flag, and process those bytes that are already saved in buffer. This allows me to use DMA with variable length data. Like in article I've just posted.

Comment: @bielu000 Yeah but the catch is that the line is gonna stay idle after the data is received. If doing what you are attempting, you need to enable the idle interrupt upon catching the first byte of data only, then disable it once more after you've gotten the idle interrupt. Seems like a cumbersome way to do things, I'd either use all out DMA with no interupts, or parse the data byte by byte through the interrupt, not something in between. But I have never used UART or DMA on this part so I don't know the details.

Comment: @Lundin The interrupt won't be generated constantly. The documentation says: "The IDLE bit will not be set again until the RXNE bit has been set itself (i.e. a new idle line occurs)."

Comment: Thanks grzegorz. So there is no need to do any workaround - it should works as I described.

Answer (score 0):

The STM32 Reference Manual explains that the IDLE interrupt is generated whenever IDLE=1 in the USART_ISR register.  The IDLE bit in USART_ISR is set by the hardware when an Idle Line is detected.  It is cleared by software, writing 1 to the IDLECF in the USART_ICR register.  I'm guessing that you need to clear this within the ISR to prevent the interrupt from being immediately reasserted.  Try adding something like this line to `usart1_isr()`.

```
USART1_ICR = USART_ICR_IDLECF;  // Clear Idle flag in the USART_ISR register.
```

Comment: Yes, but following the documentation: It is cleared by a software sequence (an read to the USART_SR register followed by a read to the USART_DR register). as you can see I do it in my code, but for some reason the flag is not cleared.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at a reference manual for the STM32L4, which says write to USART1_ICR.  Now I see the reference manual for the STM32F10x says read from USART_SR and USART_DR.